# Prove that $Z =\sum_{j=1}^{n}S_{j}$ is distributed as $\mathrm{NB}(\frac{n\alpha}{\ln(1-\delta)},1-\delta)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Prove that $Z=\sum_{j=1}^{n}S_{j}$ is distributed as $$\mathrm{NegativeBinomial}\left(\frac{n\alpha}{\ln(1-\delta)},1-\delta\right)$$

Being $S_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}$ where $N$ is distributed as $\mathrm{Poisson}(\alpha)$ and $f_{X_i}(x)=\dfrac{-\delta^\epsilon}{\epsilon \log(1-\delta)}$ with $\epsilon=1,2,\dots$

The thing here is that i don't have any clue how to get the pdf of $S$, im guessing maybe with the MGF I could get something, but I´m not sure at all, a full lenght explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify--what more precisely is the distribution of the $X_i$? I presume $f_{X_i}$ is a density function, but what is its argument? Are $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ parameters, ir is $\epsilon$ the argument? Is $X_i$ discrete?

Comment: This was a questión from a test a had this semester, literally this is how it was written. I also think $\epsilon$ is the argument,so it has to be discrete being $\epsilon=1,2,...$

Comment: Can you edit your question? It doesn't make sense that $Z$ is a sum of $S_j$'s, which in turn are sums of $X_i$'s. Are you sure that this is "literally how it was written"?

Comment: @mathse: It looks like each $S_i$ is a random sum of $X_i$'s, and $Z$ is a fixed sum of $S_i$'s.

Comment: Ok, yeah, this could be. In any case, $S_j$ has a NB distribution and is the sum of NB distributed RV also NB distributed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** I think that [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Representation_as_compound_Poisson_distribution) gives a proof of the fact that the (Poisson) random sum of logarithmic distributions is NB distributed.

Then use the fact that the (non-random) sum of NB distributed RV's is NB distributed.

Comment: You can upvote me if it helped you :D

Comment: I need 15 reputation tu do that, sorry I'm new